# Can the permutation group of a matrix be generated by the subset of row permutation and column permutation?

Tags: matrices, permutation-groups

Consider a 3*3 matrix 
$\left( \begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{m_{11}}}&{{m_{12}}}&{{m_{13}}}\\
{{m_{21}}}&{{m_{22}}}&{{m_{23}}}\\
{{m_{31}}}&{{m_{32}}}&{{m_{33}}}
\end{array} \right)$ and its permutation group, which consists of all the possible permutation over its element such as $\left( {{m_{22}},{m_{33}}} \right) \cdot \left( {{m_{11}},{m_{21}},{m_{32}}} \right)$. I wonder whether all these permutations can be expressed as a composition of several row permutation and column permutation? If so, does it still hold when we consider a non-square matrix?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the answer is no.  As you have defined it, there are $9!$ elements in your permutation group, but there are only $6$ permutation matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Of course **not**, for the following reason. When applying either a row or a column permutation, then the set of products
$$m_{1\sigma(1)}\cdots m_{n\sigma(n)},\qquad\sigma\in\frak{S}_n$$
is unchanged. On the contrary, if you apply another permutation of the entries, this becomes false. For instance, if you apply the transposition $(m_{22},m_{33})$, then the product $m_{12}m_{21}m_{33}$ becomes $m_{12}m_{21}m_{22}$.